# Content-Range missing header

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm facing this error and I don't really understand why. Other ask don't contains usefully information so I try to ask again providing more details
[Content range missing header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwF6h.png)
[Response detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU6vQ.png)

Comment: make the effort to both both your code and the error in the question, it's barely readeable if at all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the documentation:

> The simple REST client expects the API to include a `Content-Range` header in the response to `GET_LIST` calls. The value must be the total number of resources in the collection. This allows admin-on-rest to know how many pages of resources there are in total, and build the pagination controls.

Your header does not have the requested format:

`Content-Range: posts 0-24/319`

Comment: if you look at the first picture you'll notice that the header Content-Range is set in the response

Comment: And I can notice that it does not follow the documentation too. For a `post` resource, it should look like `Content-Range: posts 0-24/319`